# KVO for manually implemented properties

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

According to [Ensuring KVC Compliance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html),

> For properties that are an attribute or a to-one relationship, this requires that your class:
>
> - Implement a method named `-<key>`, `-is<Key>`, or have an instance variable `<key>` or `_<key>`.

**What is the best way to add observers to "FAKE" properties like the following?**

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL shortlisted; 

#pragma mark - Fake properties

- (BOOL)shortlisted
{
    return [self.provider isJobShortlisted:self];
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Dependent Keys

If you simply have one key which is dependent on another key *of the same object*, you can override [`+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:). (See also [this article](http://www.notesfromandy.com/2011/06/15/keypathsforvaluesaffectingvalueforkey-doing-it-wrong/) for a common pitfall.)

The KVO documentation has information about keys dependent on *other objects*, but unfortunately it looks like this only has built-in support on OS X (not iOS).

### Manual Notifcations

If you're implementing a completely custom property, the section on [**Manual Change Notification**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-SW1) in the KVO docs has all the information you need. The key points are (with quotes from the docs):

- > A class that implements manual notification must override the NSObject implementation of [`automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:). ... For properties that perform manual notification, the subclass implementation of `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` should return `NO`.
- > To implement manual observer notification, you invoke
  >   [`willChangeValueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/willChangeValueForKey:) before changing the value, and [`didChangeValueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/didChangeValueForKey:) after changing the value.

  (If you change multiple properties, you can nest these calls.)
- > In the case of an ordered to-many relationship, you must specify not only the key that changed, but also the type of change and the indexes of the objects involved.

  For this you use the methods [`willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:) and [`didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:).

Comment: No, it implemented before me! Mmm, but "shortlisted" property has "readonly" modifier...

Comment: @InjectIOS That's fine — KVO still needs to know when to send notifications. You call this method ***internally*** when you do something that will change the value.

Comment: @InjectIOS I think I might understand your concern — check my updated answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Actually I looking for best way - use notifications, or delegates inside VC or like you said

Comment: We have an array of NSStrings jobKeys, and getter of "shortlisted" property [self.provider isJobShortlisted:self]; return [jobKeys containsObject:jobKey];

Comment: @InjectIOS I think your logic is backwards. I would recommend that you use `@property BOOL shortlisted;` on each job and `@synthesize shortlisted`, and then `-isJobShortlisted:` would return the result of the `shortlisted` property. Without more contextual information it's hard to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I also was thinking about this solution

Comment: We have method 
- (void)addToShortlist:(CompleteBlock)complete
{
    if (self.shortlisted) return;
...
}  

Is it correct add manually notification "willChangeValueForKey" here?

Comment: @InjectIOS let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9776/discussion-between-jtbandes-and-inject-ios)